# Combining two change functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I combine these two different uses of `.change` to make one function?

Both are using `$('input[name="menu"]')` but are semantically different so I am not sure the proper way to combine the two.

I tried putting `$(".menu[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);` inside of the `.on("change"), function ()` without any luck.

```js
$('input[name="menu"]')
  .change(function() {
    $(".menu[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  })
  .change();
$(function() {
  $('input[name="menu"]').on("change", function() {
    if (
      $(this)
      .closest('[class*="list-"]')
      .is(".list-custom")
    ) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this)
          .siblings("[data-icon]")
          .attr("data-prefix", "fas")
          .closest(".launch-icon")
          .addClass("checked");
      } else {
        $(this)
          .siblings("[data-icon]")
          .attr("data-prefix", "far")
          .closest(".launch-icon")
          .removeClass("checked");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just merge the function bodies.

Comment: The first change handler has one line of code in the function body.  What happens when you just put that one line of code at the beginning or end of the second change handler's function body?  Does it not work in some way?

Comment: I made an edit to the post with what I tried

Comment: Maybe show your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me, i will merge your code like this, but if you are searching for a real solution to your problems, please include the html markup and a code snippet that works.

```
// Starting point.

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Register listener for the change event.

    $('input[name="menu"]').change(function()
    {
        // This was on the first listener of change event.

        $(".menu[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);

        // This was on the second listener of change event.

        if ($(this).closest('[class*="list-"]').is(".list-custom"))
        {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                $(this).siblings("[data-icon]").attr("data-prefix", "fas")
                       .closest(".launch-icon").addClass("checked");
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).siblings("[data-icon]").attr("data-prefix", "far")
                       .closest(".launch-icon").removeClass("checked");
            }
        }
    });

    // Trigger a change event on the input element.
    // This was after the first event listener (why?)

    $('input[name="menu"]').change();
});
```